# Transactions over very very large entity group

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I am trying to design a data model which can hold a very large amount of data, does anyone with experience in large volumes of data have any feedback on this, ie:

```
// example only, not meant to compile
public class TransactionAccount {
    private long balance;
    private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    ....
    public long getBalance() { return balance; }
}
private class Transaction {
    public Date date;
    public long amount;
}
```

Based on what I have read, the only way to get transactional integrity on  inserting a `Transaction` and updating `balance` is to make it one entity group.

However over time there would be millions of transactions for a particular `TransactionAccount`. The number of writes to this entity group would be low, but the reads would be much higher.

I know it could possibly be sharded, however reading the `balance` is a very frequent operation, and sharding it would make one of the most common operations `getBalance()` the slowest operation.

Comment: There is a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342603/how-do-you-propery-add-manipulate-thousands-of-children-in-an-entity-group) discussing [how to manage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342603/how-do-you-propery-add-manipulate-thousands-of-children-in-an-entity-group) an entity group with tens of thousands of children objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrangement you describe should work fine. If your entity group grows excessively big (we're talking hundreds of megabytes of transactions before this becomes an issue), you could write a procedure to 'roll up' old transactions: transactionally replace a set of old transaction records with a single one for the sum of those transactions, in order to maintain the invariant that the balance is equal to the sum of all transactions. If you still need to store a record of these old, 'rolled up' transactions, you can make a copy of them in a separate entity group before you perform the roll-up.

Comment: This is an excellent idea, you could for example, have a "cron" task that checks for entities with more than X records and then simply move, the oldest X transactions to another entity group.

Comment: Just curious, where do you get the figure "hundreds of megabytes" as a guideline? Wouldn't it be a bit too much to have a "Transaction" object  loaded into memory that contains 100Mb of data?

Comment: By hundreds of megabytes, I mean the size of the entity group as a whole - the account and all its transactions - not the size of a single entity. I get the hundreds of megabytes guideline from my own experience as a Bigtable administrator. :)

Comment: Thanks! I have been tossing around in my head all weekend ways to try and split the data up, its difficult when you are new to JDO and bigtables. It leads me to another more practical question on how you would actually deal with a `Set<Transaction>` or `List<Transaction>`, I am not sure how to manage this if there are literally 100Mb of objects, ie 1 million objects

Comment: In that case, you would be better off having the child entity reference the parent, but not have it in a list. I'm not sure how that's done in JDO, though.

Comment: the nunmber of entities in a given entity group actually isn't a big concern. it's unusual, but an entity group with millions of entities is definitely doable, and i don't think it would be a problem.

the only real bottleneck that entity groups impose on scaling is write throughput, not data volume.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that `Transaction` and `TransactionAccount` must be in the same entity group in order to do the transactional insert and update operation.

The reason to shard is to reduce write contention but you say this will be a low write entity, so sharding is not needed here.

To keep the size of your entity groups down, you can device some type of archiving process.  For example, if this is for a bank account, then when the monthly statement is generated you could archive that month's worth of transactions.

Comment: This is close, however a month boundary may not be the best way to do it.. as in peak periods a lot can happen in a month.