# How do you properly add/manipulate thousands of children in an entity group?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

This further to my [previous question on handling large numbers of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331472/transactions-over-very-very-large-entity-group) in BigTables/JDO.

Assuming a `TransactionAccount` could end up with as many as 10,000 objects in its `transactions` list, how does this work with Goodle app engine?

How do you add objects to  such a large list without the whole list being loaded into memory? (The assumption is that 10,000 objects shouldn't be loaded into memory?)

*I am not trying to ask you how to do my homework, I just have no idea where to start to solve this, the app engine documentation and google searching is not helping :(*

```
// example only, not meant to compile
@PersistenceCapable
public class TransactionAccount {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    public Key key;
    private long balance;
    private long transactionCount;
    @Element(dependent = "true")
    private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    ....
    public long getBalance() { return balance; }
}

@PersistenceCapable
private class Transaction {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    public Key key;
    public Date date;
    public long amount;
}
```

This question is raised but not resolved [in the following google groups post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/de7a91d92b2bc6be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try marking the transactions property `@NotPersistent`, so that it's not stored in the datastore at all. you can get the Transaction entities for a given TransactionAccount with an [ancestor query](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html) (more in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/b07c62030e7bbcb8#)). with that, you should be able to store arbitrarily many transactions for a given account, since they're not all stored in the account entity.

a less drastic measure would be to mark the transactions property unindexed with this annotation:

```
@Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.unindexed", value="true")
```

the account's transactions would still be stored in the list, but they wouldn't be indexed, which would make it a bit more feasible. still, you'd hit the 1MB entity size limit around 10-100k transactions, which wouldn't be a problem if you use `@NotPersistent`.