# More than 5 entity groups in a Cross Group (XG) transaction

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

Background:

I recently updated to JDO 2.0 / Datanucleus 3.1.1 in the GAE SDK 1.7.3. I have 2nd level caching going to memcache, and I've found that I'm seeing stale data in the cache when I do certain operations on child entities. For example, when I delete some children from a set, then a few moments later add new ones back in, then it updates the datastore, but not the cache, so subsequent reads are sending back the stale data.

Anyway, that's a separate issue - my workaround has been to put the update in a transaction, so that the cache entry gets invalidated and removed (transactions will not write changes to memcache).

This works. However, I have quite a few unowned relationships, so sometimes I'll be updating more than 5 entity groups - for example I do a bulk flag operation that flags a whole load of rows as 'done'. The strange thing is IT WORKS, despite it saying explicitly in the Google documentation that XG transactions are limited to 5 entity groups. Am I missing something here?

I should also mention that I haven't explicity enabled XG transactions for JDO - again, it just seems to work. The logs suggest that it is, in fact, doing transactions.

I'm just a little bit baffled. Is this likely to stop working in the future? Is JDO somehow managing the size of the transactions? Are XG transactions managed automatically by the latest JDO, or turned on by default?

Comment: The GAE plugin does no "automanaging" of XG transactions; that's for you to control. All public at http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine%2Fdatanucleus

Comment: Thanks @DataNucleus. Then I'm baffled as to how this works.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is an answer, but I can tell you that the 5 entity group limit is definitely enforced (or at least was as of SDK 1.7.1) as I've battled with it many times.

First are you sure you don't have something in your jdoconfig.xml along the lines of:

```
<property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="true"/>
```

I also had many unowned relationships in my model, and my solution for getting around the entity group limit was to place several of the objects in the same entity group. Basically I have something along the lines of:

```
X -- has a -- A
  \- has a -- B
  \- has a -- C
```

but A is also the parent of B, which is the parent of C - therefore only 2 entity groups, even though all of the relationships with X are marked @Unowned.

Incidentally it also means that you only need to persist A.

Since you don't share any details of your object model, I can't say if this is anything like what you have...

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. I have two kinds User and Workout. Each user has many workouts, which are unowned. This was implemented in JDO 1.0 so, then aren't @unowned, I just manage it myself using Key objects. Each of the entities is a root entity.

Comment: Then I agree, if your Workout keys don't have User key as the parent, they should be in separate entity groups and fail when you try and modify more than 5 in a transaction. Perhaps consider making the User key the parent of the Workout, and if you're concerned with the number of Workout entities getting too big, maybe read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342603/how-do-you-properly-add-manipulate-thousands-of-children-in-an-entity-group